# Spring Listener for MongoDB data insertion

Tags: spring, mongodb, server-sent-events

I have a requirement where I need to display data inserted into a particular MongoDB collection onto a User's dashboard in real time. Please note data maybe inserted by this user or other users. The dashboard is part of a Spring MVC web-application. The MongoDB data-layer is written in Spring Data.

I intend to use Server-sent events approach to push the newly inserted data to the dashboard. I am looking for an efficient way to listen to data insertion using Spring. I am even open to a non-Spring approach to implement the Listener that will eventually talk to my Spring SSE emitter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all the save goes through your spring-data layer, then you can make use of Mongo Listener Life cycle events [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.mapping-usage.events).

```
@Component
public class MongoListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<Account> 
{

    @Override
    public void onAfterSave(AfterSaveEvent<E> event) {

            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOG.debug("onAfterSave({}, {})", event.getSource(), event.getDocument());
            }
        }
}
```

If not you would have to read mongo oplog and process or create a capped collection and use tailable cursors.
[here](https://github.com/pvpkiran/spring5/tree/master/src/main/java/in/phani/springboot/spring5) is a sample project using tailable cursors.

Comment: Will the life-cycle events created in application context of user 'A'  i.e. initiated by 'A' be made aware to user 'B' via the Mongo Listener  ?

Comment: when you say user A, and B are these application users or mongo users? And also doyou have separate mongo users created for different users?

Comment: application users.certain user data that is written to a specific mongodb collection needs to visible on dashboard of all application users

Comment: what matters for spring-data is the mongoTemplate thaat is used, doesn't matter who your application user is. So it should work. give it a try

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via [OpLog collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) and [Tailable Cursors](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/tailable-cursors/) in MongoDB. For example, get MongoDB OpLog Collection by using flags `QUERYOPTION_TAILABLE | QUERYOPTION_AWAITDATA` via your MongoDB framework (for example MongoDB Java Driver) and do the following query

```
MongoCursor<> cursor = db.getCollection('oplog.rs').find({ns:"collectionName", op:"i"})
```

where `"collectionName"` is the name of your collection and `"i"` is insert operation. After receiving events from the cursor you can send the events into a shared stream.

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Spring Data to provide an example for this, but the approach should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

May take a look at this library: [spring-boot-up-data-mongodb](https://github.com/wnameless/spring-boot-up-data-mongodb). It allows user to declare annotation driven events in your entity classes.

```java
@Document
public class ThisEntity {

  ...

  @AfterSaveToMongo
  public void updateDashboard(SourceAndDocument sad) {
    var thisEntity = sad.getSource(ThisEntity.class)
  }
}
```

BTW, I am the author of this library.